# How can I rotate a report in SSRS (switch columns and rows)

Tags: sql, reporting-services, pivot

In a stored proc I massage data into this format using

```
Select 
'TicketsReceived', Sum(Category1) as Category1, Sum(Category2) as Category2 ... etc
Union All
'TicketsResolved', Sum(Category1) as Category1, Sum(Category2 as Category2) ... etc
...
```

[Data from stored proc]

[image]

I also don't want to use the category column names for headings and so I have a simple lookup table (values here are fictitious examples)
[category description lookup]

[image]

The desired result should look more like this:
[enter image description here]

[image]

If I use a matrix in SSRS, and set the Columns header to AggregationType then the columns look exactly like I want but what confuses me is that the row header also wants a column as a datasource, and that messes with my brain.  I can see that I probably could add a first row that has all the category descriptions in it.  That's something I could do but why can't I just set the columns to rows and rows to columns and let it just rotate the table?  help please.

Comment: You need some column to break up the data into four lines otherwise you'll just have one total line. Maybe CROSS APPLY with single column of CAT_Num with 1 - 4? But then you'd need to sum each Category like CAT 2  `=SUM(IIF(Fields!CAT_Num.Value = 2, Category2, 0)` Might be better to UNPIVOT in SQL and then use the SSRS Tablix to pivot the Count Types.

Comment: What does your raw data look like that you process in the Stored Proc? It sounds like it might be easier to **not** pivot the data in the SP like you are doing. (I know your not using PIVOT but the effect is the same). Then you can just use a matrix to pivot in SSRS as Hannover is also suggesting.

Comment: @Alan Shofield
well the original data doesn't look much better.
it basically looks like 
`code`
ID,Categ1,categ2,categ3,... ,date received,date resolved
1,N,Y,N,2/1/23,3/1/23
2,Y,N,N,2/28/23,3/5/23

Comment: Can you edit your question and show a small sample of the data, its hard to visualise with it unformatted in the comments.

Comment: Also, could you also show more of the SP code as there may be a way to update that  to get half way there, just need to see the FROM and WHERE Clauses really